# Llinked list not printing correctly

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been trying to make a simple program that takes the user input, until they press done. And when they do the program will print out everything that they have typed. I feel I have got most of it working, and the program compiles fine but when I enter the input and then press done it will output done for as many lines as I have entered the input. Ive drawn it out, feel that this code should work. Also i'm very new to C. So if anyone can let me know whats wrong or even give me suggestions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct llist {          
struct llist* nxt; 
char* string;
};              

void add(struct llist **tail, char* str) { 
    struct llist* n_ptr = (struct llist*)malloc(sizeof(struct llist));
    (**tail).string = str; 
    (**tail).nxt = n_ptr;   
        (*tail) = n_ptr; 
    n_ptr->nxt = (struct llist*)0;
};

void print(struct llist *Head) {
    struct llist* ptr;
    ptr = Head;
    while(ptr->nxt){ 
        printf("%s\n", ptr->string);
        fflush(stdout);
        (ptr = (ptr->nxt)); }
}

int main() {
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t size = 100; 
    char* done = "done";

    struct llist head; 
    struct llist* tail = (struct llist*)malloc(sizeof(struct llist));

    tail = &head; 

    do { 
    getline(&line, &size, stdin); 
    add( &tail , line ) ;   
    } while ( strncmp(line, done, 4) != 0 );

    print(&head);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list only contains a *pointer* to the data, not the data itself. So if the data added to the list changes, the data *in* the list changes too. For every call to `add`, `str` is the same. So you've just added the same pointer to the list over and over.

For a quick, ugly fix, change:

```
(**tail).string = str;
```

to:

```
(**tail).string = strdup(str);
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that and it worked perfectly, except from a warning from the compiler.

Comment: From a missing `#include <string.h>`?

Comment: Maybe, I'm pretty new so I don't know what all of these warnings mean but it says, cmdline.c:11:20: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’ [enabled by default]

Comment: Sounds like a missing header.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes for you.

- `getline()` takes a pointer to a buffer.  The text will be stored wherever the pointer says.  Where will your text go?  You should either do this:

`line = malloc(size);`

or perhaps

`char line[100];`

Either of these will fix the problem.  But since `getline()` will dynamically grow the buffer if it is not large enough, maybe the `malloc()` solution is preferable.  (I don't know if `getline()` will try to call `free()` or not when it dynamically grows the buffer; if it does, then the `malloc()` one is very preferable.)

EDIT: You can ignore the above point!  It turns out that `getline()` is smart enough that if you start out with a null pointer, it will allocate a buffer for you.  So your code is correct as written.  Sorry about that; I am not familiar with `getline()`.

- Your linked list code mostly calls `malloc()` to make new nodes.  But for some reason you declare a single node, to be `head`, statically.  That's okay for a little program like this one, but it will be confusing if you ever write a large program; when you go to free the linked list you would need to be careful not to free the first node (since it wasn't allocated using `malloc()`).  Personally I would make both `head` and `tail` be pointers, and start them both set to `NULL` (for a length-zero linked list).  The easiest way to do this would be to make your `add()` function take an argument for the `head` pointer, and make it set up `head` when adding the very first struct to the linked list.  You would also need to be a little bit careful because when you are adding your very fist struct to the linked list, your `tail` isn't set yet, so you shouldn't try to link a new node onto the previous node before there is one.  Thus, your first call to `add()` should set `head` and `tail` to point to a brand-new instance of your struct, and the new instance should have its `next` pointer set to null; other calls to `add()` should then link the new structs in to the existing linked list.
- In real programs you would always check the return values of functions.  It is possible for `malloc()` to fail; you shouldn't just assume it always works.  But if you are doing this for a class, and you don't have to do those error checks, I guess you can skip it.  It never hurts to learn careful habits early, though.
- As noted in @David Schwartz's answer, you should call `strdup()` to get a copy of each string.

Comment: I was thinking about making the head a pointer, but the example of a llist had it statically. I don't understand fully why i should call strdup() though.

Comment: Here is why you need to call strdup(): You have a buffer called `line` that you will pass to `getline()`.  Each call to `getline()` will re-use this same buffer.  The same space will be used for each new string; that means each new string will overwrite the previous string.  If all you do is store the address of `line` in each node, then when your list prints at the end, it will just print the word `done` over and over (because that was the last thing typed into the `line` buffer).  `strdup()` allocates enough space to store the string, copies the string into the space, and returns a pointer.

Comment: I was mistaken in my first point and edited the text to reflect this.  `getline()` will allocate a buffer if you start it with a null pointer so your code is fine as-is.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct llist head; 
struct llist* tail = (struct llist*)malloc(sizeof(struct llist));

tail = &head;
```

I'd also like to point out that the malloc here is unnecessary. You are discarding it anyway with the assignment on the third line causing a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {FAILURE, SUCCESS} ReturnType;

typedef struct node_t Node;
struct node_t {
    Node* next;
    char* data;
};

Node* nodeCreate(char* str) {
    Node* res = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (res == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    res->data = (char*) malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (res->data == NULL) {
        free(res);
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(res->data, str);
    res->next = NULL;

    return res;
}    

void nodeDestroy(Node* node) {
    free(node->data);
    free(node);
}    

typedef struct list_t {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
} List;

List* listCreate() {
    List* res = (List*) malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (res == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    res->head = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (res->head == NULL) {
        free(res);
        return NULL;
    }
    res->head->next = NULL;
    res->head->data = NULL;
    res->tail = res->head;

    return res;
}

void listDestroy(List* list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    Node* curr = list->head;
    Node* next = NULL;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        next = curr->next;
        nodeDestroy(curr);
        curr = next;
    }
    free(list);
}

ReturnType listAdd(List* list, char* str) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    Node* newNode = nodeCreate(str);
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    list->tail->next = newNode;
    list->tail = list->tail->next;

    return SUCCESS;
};

void listPrint(List* list) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    Node* curr = list->head->next;
    while(curr != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 100

int main() {
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char* done = "done";

    List* list = listCreate();
    if (list == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    do {
        scanf("%s", line);
        if (listAdd(list , line) == FAILURE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failure!\n");
            listDestroy(list);
            return 0;
        }
    } while (strncmp(line, done, 4) != 0);

    listPrint(list);

    listDestroy(list);

    return 0;
}
```